# I cant get the element locator in Ie to work with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

Can someone help with why I am getting this error? I am new to scripting but this has had me stuck for a few days now. (I have to use internet explorer). Thanks so much for all your help!

**ERROR: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == input.k-textbox**

HTML:

```
driver = webdriver.Ie(IEDriverManager().install())
#this will open up the HighJump Site
url = "http://hjweb.theblacktux.net:30000/workspace/Default.html"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.k-textbox")
username.send_keys("sa")
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```

Comment: HTML: <input class="k-textbox" type="text" placeholder="User Name" data-bind="attr: {maxlength: _maxLength, style: _style, placeholder: _placeholder}, disable: _disabled, textInput: _value, setFocus: _viewActions, focus: _hasFocus">

Comment: First check if there are any iframes in the page.

Comment: I tested your python & HTML code with the IE 11 browser. It works fine for me. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/dhS1fgu). So it can be possible that you are not locating that element properly in your python code. If possible then try to share some more HTML code. You can also check the source code by inspecting the element. Other then that I noticed that in a code you are waiting for 20 seconds. If the page is taking long time to get load then make sure that the page is loaded completely and then try to find for the element.

Comment: Ok I'll share more of the HTML code. I don't think it has any iframes.


<input class="k-textbox" type="text" placeholder="User Name" data-bind="attr: {maxlength: _maxLength, style: _style, placeholder: _placeholder}, disable: _disabled, textInput: _value, setFocus: _viewActions, focus: _hasFocus"> <input class="k-textbox" type="text" placeholder="User Name" data-bind="attr: {maxlength: _maxLength, style: _style, placeholder: _placeholder}, disable: _disabled, textInput: _value, setFocus: _viewActions, focus: _hasFocus">

Comment: Looks like you have pasted the same line of HTML twice that is not giving any idea about the issue. I want to confirm with you if you visit the site manually how much time it takes to load completely? Can you see this textbox is loaded while the page gets open in the browser?