# Assistance with selenium send key python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I am new to python scripting and am not understanding why I am getting this error. For some reason, I cannot get it to send_keys to that element.

**ERROR: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:**

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = "http://hjweb.theblacktux.net:30000/workspace/Default.html"

driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.k-textbox")))

element.send_keys("sa")

element.click()

```
HTML:<hj-textbox data-hj-test-id="username" params="value: username.value, placeholder: 'User Name', hasFocus: username.hasFocus, disabled: isDataEntryDisabled"><input class="k-textbox" type="text" data-bind="attr: {maxlength: _maxLength, style: _style, placeholder: _placeholder}, disable: _disabled, textInput: _value, setFocus: _viewActions, focus: _hasFocus" style="" placeholder="User Name"></hj-textbox>
```

ISSUE WITH FINDING ELEMENT BY XPATH

Ok, I have another question! So I am able to run this line of code without getting an error. (I'm assuming the element can be located using that xpath since I do not get an error.)

element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//hj-textbox[@data-hj-test-id='username']")

But when I run this line along with that one I get this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//hj-textbox[@data-hj-test-id='username']")
element.send_keys("TEST")

So I then tried doing

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//hj-textbox[@data-hj-test-id='username']")
element.send_keys("TEST")

And I get the error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with xpath == //hj-textbox[@data-hj-test-id='username']

Comment: Please provide the entire error output.

Comment: I suggest you do not create [duplicate threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64000961/i-cant-get-the-element-locator-in-ie-to-work-with-selenium) for the same issue. Looks like you have paste the same line of HTML twice that is not giving any idea about the issue. I want to confirm with you if you visit the site manually how much time it takes to load completely? Can you see this textbox is loaded while page get open in the browser?

Comment: Sorry about creating a new thread. If I visit the site manually it takes about 5 seconds to fully load. Yes I can see the textbox when the page is open

Comment: Please provide more HTML code, if there is any sensitive information then you can replace it with dummy text. We do not require any confidential information but more code may help to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I have added more HTML code in the question

Comment: I again try to make a test with your updated HTML and XPath. This code works on my side and it is entering the value in the textbox. `username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='k-textbox'][@placeholder='User Name']")
username.send_keys("sa")` You can have a test on your side and let us know about your test result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try waiting for the element to be present and then selecting it?
Simply use implicit wait to streamline the wait for an element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.implicitly_wait(4) # CHANGE THE NUMBER OF SECONDS IF NEEDED
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.k-textbox")
element.send_keys("sa")
```

Alternatively have you tried finding the element by xpath?

Comment: So i added the driver.implicity_wait(5) and i got the same exact error. I have tried locating the element by xpath and it still doesn't complete the send keys function. It gives me the error that the element is able to be found.

Comment: I'll try and add my xpath issue to the question.

Comment: I added it to the original question